# Simplicial approximation theorem for toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Given abstract simplicial complexes $K$ and $L$, one constructs topological spaces $|K|$ and $|L|$. Simplicial approximation theorem says for any continuous map $f: |K|\to |L|$ that there exists further subdivision $K'$ of $K$, and a map of abstract simplicial complexes $g: K'\to L$ such that $f$ is homotopic to the map $|g|:|K'|\simeq |K|\to |L|$ induced by $g$.

Over to toric varieties: toric morphisms are maps arising from linear maps of lattices/semigroup homomorphisms. But suppose $f: X\to Y$ is a non-toric map between toric varieties, does there exist a subdivision of their fans and a toric morphism that "approximates" $f$?

Comment: Welcome new user.  I do not see how this could work already when both the domain and the target are the projective line.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I see that simply subbing in "subdivision" in this context doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The topology of the (underlying complex analytic) space of morphisms from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to a toric variety is understood, e.g., by the proofs for toric varieties of the Cohen-Jones-Segal conjecture.  This space is not compact, and there are compactifications that are functorial, hence equivariant.  There is an equivariant stratification, and the fixed locus of each stratum is understood in terms of toric morphisms.  But there is also some "normal data" that goes into reconstructing the topology ala Seifert-van Kampen.  So, in some sense, toric morphisms are the key.